# Change/Add SVG Matrix

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, matrix

### Problem:

**So I edited the question accordingly to what I am actually trying to achieve.**

I have three SVG which were created by converting different versions of floors plans, thus the viewbox and the coordinates of those three SVG are not matching each other.

What I am currently trying to do and fail (also my approach in the example/guide below) is to:

A)
First I need to rescale/position the original SVG (limegreen) in my example to match the second one (crimson) and the persisting grafics should overlap. I try this by calculating the difference in the first `g` element, which seems to work fine by now.

B)
Now I am to rescale/position it again to a third (aqua) SVG, which in this test case is a copy of the original one (limegreen). Unfortunately I am unable to property overlap the once rescaled/positioned SVG back to its original layout by using the same `g` element as reference.

In all these steps I am only able to adjust/alter the `path` elements, except for the `viewBox` change.

### Example:

The four circle shaped pathes at the bottom right are supposed to overlap after both transformations (limegreen & crimson, limegreen & aqua).

Also be aware that Firefox does not seem to support `getBBox()` on `g` elements (always empty - working on that), so better to test in chrome.

```js
function Transform(element, transform, svg){
 var tMatrix = element.transform.baseVal.numberOfItems ? element.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix : element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(svg.createSVGTransform()).matrix;

 tMatrix.f = tMatrix.f + transform.f * tMatrix.d;
 tMatrix.a = tMatrix.a * transform.a;
 tMatrix.d = tMatrix.d * transform.d
};

function Step1(){
 alert('This is my initial SVG (limegreen).');

 //going to use this later on
 var tSVG3 = document.querySelector('#svgStep1').cloneNode(true);
 tSVG3.id = 'svgStep3';
 document.body.appendChild(tSVG3);

 document.querySelector('#btn1').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 document.querySelector('#btn2').className = ''
};

function Step2(){
 alert('This initial SVG now gets fused with a second SVG (crimson).');

 document.querySelector('#svgStep1').style.opacity = '0.5';
 document.querySelector('#svgStep2').style.display = 'block';

 document.querySelector('#btn2').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 document.querySelector('#btn3').className = ''
};

function Step3(){
 alert('As we can see, the second SVG (crimson) is scaled differently (bigger) than the first one. Now to solve this issue we get the difference of those two by the group with the id "EQ_MOBILIAR" (the only group here).');

 document.querySelector('#btn3').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 document.querySelector('#btn4').className = ''
};

function Step4(){
 alert('So first we set the viewbox of the initial SVG (limegreen) to the same values as the second SVG (crimson)');

 var tPoint1 = document.querySelector('#svgStep1 > g#EQ_MOBILIAR').getBBox();
 var tPoint2 = document.querySelector('#svgStep2 > g#EQ_MOBILIAR').getBBox();

 window._Transformation1 = {
  a: tPoint2.width / tPoint1.width,
  d: tPoint2.height / tPoint1.height,
  e: tPoint2.x - tPoint1.x,
  f: tPoint2.y - tPoint1.y
 };

 var tViewBox1= document.querySelector('#svgStep1').viewBox.baseVal;
 var tViewBox2 = document.querySelector('#svgStep2').viewBox.baseVal;

 tViewBox1.x = tViewBox2.x;
 tViewBox1.y = tViewBox2.y;
 tViewBox1.width = tViewBox2.width;
 tViewBox1.height = tViewBox2.height;

 document.querySelector('#btn4').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 document.querySelector('#btn5').className = ''
};

function Step5(){
 alert('Now we adjust the matrix of each grafic (path/g) in the initial SVG (limegreen) to match the scale of the second (crimson) one.');
 alert('The difference of those two SVG: \n ' + JSON.stringify(window._Transformation1));

 var tSVG1 = document.querySelector('#svgStep1');
 for(var tListOfElements=tSVG1.querySelectorAll('#svgStep1 > g > *'), i=0, j=tListOfElements.length; i<j; i++){
  Transform(
   tListOfElements[i],
   window._Transformation1,
   tSVG1
  )
 };

 document.querySelector('#btn5').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 document.querySelector('#btn6').className = ''
};

function Step6(){
 alert('So far it works correctly. Yet now we try to fuse this new SVG (limegreen) with a copy of its inital state (aqua).');

 document.querySelector('#svgStep2').style.display = 'none';
 document.querySelector('#svgStep3').style.display = 'block';

 document.querySelector('#btn6').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 document.querySelector('#btn7').className = ''
};

function Step7(){
 alert('As you can see the copy of the initial SVG (aqua) is now scaled differently (smaller) that the adjusted initial one (limegreen). So we try to reverse the process with the same steps as before.');

 document.querySelector('#btn7').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 document.querySelector('#btn8').className = ''
};

function Step8(){
 alert('So first we set the viewbox of the initial SVG (limegreen) to the same values as the copy (aqua)');

 var tPoint1 = document.querySelector('#svgStep1 > g#EQ_MOBILIAR').getBBox();
 var tPoint2 = document.querySelector('#svgStep3 > g#EQ_MOBILIAR').getBBox();

/*
 var tMatrixF = 0;
 var tSVG1 = document.querySelector('#svgStep1');
 for(var tListOfElements=tSVG1.querySelectorAll('#svgStep1 > g#EQ_MOBILIAR > *'), i=0, j=tListOfElements.length; i<j; i++){
  var tElement = tListOfElements[i];
  var tMatrix = tElement.transform.baseVal.numberOfItems ? tElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix : tElement.transform.baseVal.appendItem(tSVG1.createSVGTransform()).matrix;

  tMatrixF = Math.min(tMatrixF, tMatrix.f)
 };

 tPoint1.y = tMatrixF - tPoint1.y;
 tPoint1.height = tPoint1.height + tMatrixF;
*/

 window._Transformation2 = {
  a: tPoint2.width / tPoint1.width,
  d: tPoint2.height / tPoint1.height,
  e: tPoint2.x - tPoint1.x,
  f: tPoint2.y - tPoint1.y
 };

 var tViewBox1= document.querySelector('#svgStep1').viewBox.baseVal;
 var tViewBox2 = document.querySelector('#svgStep3').viewBox.baseVal;

 document.querySelector('#btn8').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 document.querySelector('#btn9').className = ''
};

function Step9(){
 alert('Now we adjust the matrix of each grafic (path/g) in the initial SVG (limegreen) to match the scale of the copy (aqua) one.');
 alert('The difference of those two SVG: \n ' + JSON.stringify(window._Transformation2));

 var tSVG1 = document.querySelector('#svgStep1');
 for(var tListOfElements=tSVG1.querySelectorAll('#svgStep1 > g > *'), i=0, j=tListOfElements.length; i<j; i++){
  Transform(
   tListOfElements[i],
   window._Transformation2,
   tSVG1
  )
 };

 document.querySelector('#btn9').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 document.querySelector('#btn10').className = ''
};

function Step10(){
 alert('As you can see the reverse way did not work and the initial SVG (limegreen) does not overlap with its copy (aqua).');
 document.querySelector('#btn10').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
};
```

```css
.Hidden{
 display: none
}

svg{
 display: block;
 background: #e6e6fa;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
}

svg#svgStep1{
 fill: limegreen;
 outline: 1px solid green;
 z-index: 2
}


svg#svgStep1 path{
 fill: limegreen
}

svg#svgStep2{
 display: none;
 outline: 1px solid red;
 z-index: 1
}

svg#svgStep2 path{
 fill: crimson
}

svg#svgStep3{
 display: none;
 outline: 1px solid blue;
 z-index: 1
}

svg#svgStep3 path{
 fill: aqua
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- The original SVG -->
  <svg id = 'svgStep1' xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox = '0 0 2000 1540' width = '703' height = '543'>
    <g id="EQ_MOBILIAR">
      <path d="m1501.21 1140.97h239.35v227.77l-.67 3.72l-2.37 4.04l-2.23 1.95l-3.34 1.54l-4.76 .41h-225.98z" stroke="#808080"></path>
      <path d="m1258.04 1010.56l-.25 -2.37l-.73 -2.27l-1.20 -2.07l-1.59 -1.77l-1.93 -1.40l-2.18 -.97l-2.33 -.49h-2.38l-2.33 .49l-2.18 .97l-1.93 1.40l-1.59 1.77l-1.19 2.07l-.74 2.27l-.25 2.37l.25 2.37l.74 2.26l1.19 2.07l1.59 1.77l1.93 1.40l2.18 .97l2.33 .49h2.38l2.33 -.49l2.18 -.97l1.93 -1.40l1.59 -1.77l1.20 -2.07l.73 -2.26l.25 -2.37"></path>
      <path d="m1309.02 1010.56l-.25 -2.37l-.74 -2.27l-1.19 -2.07l-1.60 -1.77l-1.92 -1.40l-2.18 -.97l-2.33 -.49h-2.39l-2.33 .49l-2.17 .97l-1.93 1.40l-1.60 1.77l-1.19 2.07l-.74 2.27l-.25 2.37l.25 2.37l.74 2.26l1.19 2.07l1.60 1.77l1.93 1.40l2.17 .97l2.33 .49h2.39l2.33 -.49l2.18 -.97l1.92 -1.40l1.60 -1.77l1.19 -2.07l.74 -2.26l.25 -2.37"></path>
      <path d="m1258.04 1054.39l-.25 -2.37l-.73 -2.26l-1.20 -2.07l-1.59 -1.77l-1.93 -1.40l-2.18 -.97l-2.33 -.49h-2.38l-2.33 .49l-2.18 .97l-1.93 1.40l-1.59 1.77l-1.19 2.07l-.74 2.26l-.25 2.37l.25 2.37l.74 2.27l1.19 2.06l1.59 1.78l1.93 1.40l2.18 .97l2.33 .49h2.38l2.33 -.49l2.18 -.97l1.93 -1.40l1.59 -1.78l1.20 -2.06l.73 -2.27l.25 -2.37"></path>
      <path d="m1309.02 1054.39l-.25 -2.37l-.74 -2.26l-1.19 -2.07l-1.60 -1.77l-1.92 -1.40l-2.18 -.97l-2.33 -.49h-2.39l-2.33 .49l-2.17 .97l-1.93 1.40l-1.60 1.77l-1.19 2.07l-.74 2.26l-.25 2.37l.25 2.37l.74 2.27l1.19 2.06l1.60 1.78l1.93 1.40l2.17 .97l2.33 .49h2.39l2.33 -.49l2.18 -.97l1.92 -1.40l1.60 -1.78l1.19 -2.06l.74 -2.27l.25 -2.37"></path>
      <path d="m188.64 288.1h57.00v28.5h-57.00z"></path>
    </g>
    <g id = 'TEST'>
      <g fill="#000" transform="matrix(0.0142676 0 0 0.0142676 50, 50)">
        <g stroke-width=".39819458" transform="matrix(2.51133 0 0 2.51133 -239.06 -636.028)">
          <rect width="397" height="397" x="95.790001" y="253.86" fill="#ccc" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.19458377" stroke-miterlimit="3" ry="0" rx="0"></rect>
          <path fill="#fff" d="M200.35 466.77H385.7V578.4H200.36zm.5-137.38h186.38v53H200.86zm-39.9 52.5h30.82v31.3h-30.8z"></path>
          <path d="M432.04 365.12H395.3v-33.07c0-6.76-5.48-12.24-12.24-12.24H205.5c-6.75 0-12.24 5.5-12.24 12.3v33.07h-36.73c-6.76 0-12.24 5.48-12.24 12.24v120c0 6.76 5.42 12.25 12.2 12.25h36.72v64.54c0 4.07.82 7.12 3.98 10 1.48 1.35 3.05 2.22 4.96 2.76 1.77.5 3.52.46 5.32.46H381c1.8 0 3.56.05 5.33-.44 1.92-.53 3.5-1.4 4.96-2.75 3.13-2.9 3.95-5.95 3.95-10.04v-64.5H432c6.77 0 12.26-5.5 12.26-12.27v-120c0-6.78-5.5-12.26-12.27-12.26zM174.9 408.28c-5.92 0-10.72-4.8-10.72-10.72 0-5.9 4.8-10.7 10.72-10.7 5.92 0 10.7 4.8 10.7 10.7 0 5.92-4.78 10.72-10.7 10.72zm208.16 166.84H205.5v-96.74h177.56zm0-210H205.5V344.3c0-6.76 5.5-12.25 12.26-12.25h153.06c6.76 0 12.24 5.5 12.24 12.25z"></path>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g fill="#000" transform="matrix(0.0142676 0 0 0.0142676 1950, 1500)">
        <g stroke-width=".39819458" transform="matrix(2.51133 0 0 2.51133 -239.06 -636.028)">
          <rect width="397" height="397" x="95.790001" y="253.86" fill="#ccc" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.19458377" stroke-miterlimit="3" ry="0" rx="0"></rect>
          <path fill="#fff" d="M200.35 466.77H385.7V578.4H200.36zm.5-137.38h186.38v53H200.86zm-39.9 52.5h30.82v31.3h-30.8z"></path>
          <path d="M432.04 365.12H395.3v-33.07c0-6.76-5.48-12.24-12.24-12.24H205.5c-6.75 0-12.24 5.5-12.24 12.3v33.07h-36.73c-6.76 0-12.24 5.48-12.24 12.24v120c0 6.76 5.42 12.25 12.2 12.25h36.72v64.54c0 4.07.82 7.12 3.98 10 1.48 1.35 3.05 2.22 4.96 2.76 1.77.5 3.52.46 5.32.46H381c1.8 0 3.56.05 5.33-.44 1.92-.53 3.5-1.4 4.96-2.75 3.13-2.9 3.95-5.95 3.95-10.04v-64.5H432c6.77 0 12.26-5.5 12.26-12.27v-120c0-6.78-5.5-12.26-12.27-12.26zM174.9 408.28c-5.92 0-10.72-4.8-10.72-10.72 0-5.9 4.8-10.7 10.72-10.7 5.92 0 10.7 4.8 10.7 10.7 0 5.92-4.78 10.72-10.7 10.72zm208.16 166.84H205.5v-96.74h177.56zm0-210H205.5V344.3c0-6.76 5.5-12.25 12.26-12.25h153.06c6.76 0 12.24 5.5 12.24 12.25z"></path>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>

  <!-- The second SVG -->
  <svg id = 'svgStep2' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2000 1478" width = '703' height = '543'>
    <g id="EQ_MOBILIAR" stroke-width="0.1">
      <path d="M1440.73 916.77L1440.44 914.05L1439.6 911.46L1438.23 909.09L1436.41 907.06L1434.2 905.46L1431.7 904.35L1429.03 903.78L1426.31 903.78L1423.64 904.35L1421.14 905.46L1418.93 907.06L1417.11 909.09L1415.74 911.46L1414.9 914.05L1414.61 916.77L1414.9 919.48L1415.74 922.08L1417.11 924.44L1418.93 926.47L1421.14 928.07L1423.64 929.18L1426.31 929.75L1429.03 929.75L1431.7 929.18L1434.2 928.07L1436.41 926.47L1438.23 924.44L1439.6 922.08L1440.44 919.48L1440.73 916.77" fill="none" stroke="#000000"></path>
      <path d="M1499.1 916.77L1498.82 914.05L1497.97 911.46L1496.61 909.09L1494.78 907.06L1492.57 905.46L1490.08 904.35L1487.41 903.78L1484.68 903.78L1482.01 904.35L1479.52 905.46L1477.31 907.06L1475.48 909.09L1474.12 911.46L1473.28 914.05L1472.99 916.77L1473.28 919.48L1474.12 922.08L1475.48 924.44L1477.31 926.47L1479.52 928.07L1482.01 929.18L1484.68 929.75L1487.41 929.75L1490.08 929.18L1492.57 928.07L1494.78 926.47L1496.61 924.44L1497.97 922.08L1498.82 919.48L1499.1 916.77" fill="none" stroke="#000000"></path>
      <path d="M1440.73 966.97L1440.44 964.25L1439.6 961.66L1438.23 959.3L1436.41 957.27L1434.2 955.66L1431.7 954.55L1429.03 953.98L1426.31 953.98L1423.64 954.55L1421.14 955.66L1418.93 957.27L1417.11 959.3L1415.74 961.66L1414.9 964.25L1414.61 966.97L1414.9 969.68L1415.74 972.28L1417.11 974.64L1418.93 976.67L1421.14 978.28L1423.64 979.39L1426.31 979.95L1429.03 979.95L1431.7 979.39L1434.2 978.28L1436.41 976.67L1438.23 974.64L1439.6 972.28L1440.44 969.68L1440.73 966.97" fill="none" stroke="#000000"></path>
      <path d="M1499.1 966.97L1498.82 964.25L1497.97 961.66L1496.61 959.3L1494.78 957.27L1492.57 955.66L1490.08 954.55L1487.41 953.98L1484.68 953.98L1482.01 954.55L1479.52 955.66L1477.31 957.27L1475.48 959.3L1474.12 961.66L1473.28 964.25L1472.99 966.97L1473.28 969.68L1474.12 972.28L1475.48 974.64L1477.31 976.67L1479.52 978.28L1482.01 979.39L1484.68 979.95L1487.41 979.95L1490.08 979.39L1492.57 978.28L1494.78 976.67L1496.61 974.64L1497.97 972.28L1498.82 969.68L1499.1 966.97" fill="none" stroke="#000000"></path>
      <path d="M216.03 89.4L281.31 89.4L281.31 122.04L216.03 122.04 z" fill="none" stroke="#000000"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>

  <button id = 'btn1' onclick = 'Step1()'>Step 1</button>
  <button id = 'btn2' class = 'Hidden' onclick = 'Step2()'>Step 2</button>
  <button id = 'btn3' class = 'Hidden' onclick = 'Step3()'>Step 3</button>
  <button id = 'btn4' class = 'Hidden' onclick = 'Step4()'>Step 4</button>
  <button id = 'btn5' class = 'Hidden' onclick = 'Step5()'>Step 5</button>
  <button id = 'btn6' class = 'Hidden' onclick = 'Step6()'>Step 6</button>
  <button id = 'btn7' class = 'Hidden' onclick = 'Step7()'>Step 7</button>
  <button id = 'btn8' class = 'Hidden' onclick = 'Step8()'>Step 8</button>
  <button id = 'btn9' class = 'Hidden' onclick = 'Step9()'>Step 9</button>
  <button id = 'btn10' class = 'Hidden' onclick = 'Step10()'>Step 10</button>
</body>
```

[Here is the full guide with all the `paths` as fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/q75f21ht/)

Comment: Why do you think that one matrix is the opposite/inverse of the other?

Comment: Probably best to call [Matrix.inverse](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#__svg__SVGMatrix__inverse) and see what the answer really is.

Comment: @Ruedi.Angehrn: I am very interested in this (merging the svg of the fiddle). If you clean and organise your question I am willing to offer a bounty.

Comment: Create a [mcve] i.e. a cut down version of your problem.

Comment: Taking one of those `path` which are available on both `svg` as a reference instead of the `g` element sounds more logical to me and would avoid that firefox issue you have. Also imagine one adding or removing elements from that one `g` which would wrongly change the whole size of the group.

Comment: @Lain: Thanks, that solved it. The group changed with the transform of its children whereas the `path` itself and its `getBBox()` remained. Also it solved the issue on Firefox.